# PHP: Cookie Delete not working

Tags: php

I've created a cookie expire time 60 days... But now I am not able to delete cooking. I am using this function to delete cookie. When I refresh page then cookie is again there.

```
function delete_cookie($key_name)
{
   $expire = time() - 3600;
   setcookie($key_name, '', $expire, '/');
   unset($_COOKIE[$key_name]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function delete_cookie($key_name)
{
  $expire = time() - 3600;
  $dimain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  setcookie($key_name, '', $expire, '/', $domain);
}
```

also you don't need `unset()`

---

**Edit:**

assuming that `$key_name` is the cookie name

Comment: I already tried with this.. manual domain name and also with HTTP_HOST but not resolved. :(

Comment: what is the name of the cookie you set?

Comment: and please post the code you where you set the cookie

Comment: I tried this function now.... Key name is correct..    function delete_cookie($key_name)
{
    $expire = time() - 3600;
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    unset($_COOKIE[$key_name]);
    setcookie($key_name, '', $expire);
    setcookie($key_name, '', $expire, '/', $domain);
    setcookie($key_name, '', $expire);
    setcookie($key_name, '', $expire, '/');
    setcookie($key_name, null, $expire);
    setcookie($key_name, null, $expire, '/', $domain);
    unset($_COOKIE[$key_name]);
}  and it is workig now.

Comment: again, you don't need `unset()` to delete a cookie, all you need to do is setting its time to the past and the browser will delete it, and post the code where you `set` the cookie not the code where you `delete` it

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.